# What does "Unity" refer to on my guild card?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

So glancing at my guild card in MHGen, there's a stat being tracked called "Unity". It displays a counter - right now I'm at 0 out of 99999. The game hasn't mentioned this mechanic at all, what is it?

Comment: in MH4U it was how often you played with people you exchanged guilcards/friends with, and you got rewarded with tickets and other things. not sure how it's different in gen yet.

Comment: this stat was in MH3U as well I believe

Comment: Huh, really? I must not have noticed it in either of those games

Answer (score 2):

Your Unity will go up as you play with people whose Guild Cards you own. I'm not sure what reaching 99999 does, or if there are intermediate rewards.

Answer (score 2):

In 3U and 4U, you got VE (Bronze/Silver/Gold) tickets for raising Unity.  These tickets could be traded for the Veggie Elder for rare materials (Including items like plates, gems, the good stuff).
I've gotten VE Bronze and Silver tickets in MHGen, so I suspect it's the same.
For this reason, most people recommend sending your Guild Card whenever you play with randoms (Menu -> 2nd page -> Guild Card -> Send -> Send to All).